# getting certificates from p12 file in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography

I am stuck on this problem for many hours now and cannot find any solution. I have a p12 file which may contain some key pairs and also some certificates on their own. When I try the following code below, it gives me the list of only key pairs but not standalone certificates.

```
//open the p12 file
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource(“keychainfile”, ofType: "p12")!
let pdata : NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path)! as NSData
let dictionary = [String(kSecImportExportPassphrase!.takeRetainedValue()) : “password”]
var keyref: Unmanaged<CFArray>?
var error = SecPKCS12Import(pdata, dictionary, &keyref)

//retrieve file entries
var list = keyref!.takeRetainedValue() as NSArray
println(list.count) // finds only key pairs
```

And also part 2 of my question is that how can I retrieve only one specific certificate (by alias or name) from the p12 file instead of getting all of the entries and then looping through to find the certificate I am looking for?